# How to retrieve imploded images path in database to view in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, explode, implode

I am trying to save the multiple images path in database and upload images in root's upload/images[directory]. I have done it and its working. Images name are saved in database and and the image files are being uploaded. I just did save the images name by imploding. Now I need to explode that image in view. How can i do that? I have tried the following code in view and its not working.

```
      <?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $p['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $p['product_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $p['product_price']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $p['produce_description']; ?></td>
          <!-- <td><?php echo $p['picture']; ?> </td> -->
          <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').explode('|',$p['picture']);?>" /> </td>
          <td>
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/view/'.$p['id']); ?>">View</a> |
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/edit/'.$p['id']); ?>">Edit</a> |
              <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/delete/'.$p['id']); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

It throws this error:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Array to string conversion

    Filename: views/dashboard.php

     Line Number: 47
```

and this is my line 47:

```
     <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').explode('|',$p['picture']);?>" /> </td>
```

Incase there is mistake in my image upload function, here is my code for it:

```
    public function set_product($id=0)
     {
    #code
    // if($this->input->post('userSubmit')){
      $picture=array();
      $count=count($_FILES['picture']['name']);
      //Check whether user upload picture
      if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){

          foreach($_FILES as $value)
          {
            for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)
            {
              $_FILES['picture']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
    $_FILES['picture']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
    $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
    $_FILES['picture']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
    $_FILES['picture']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

    //Load upload library and initialize configuration
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
          // print_r($value['name'][$s]);exit;
          if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
              $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
              $picture[] = $uploadData['file_name'];
          }
          else{
              $picture = '';
          }
        }
      }
      }//end of first if

      else{
          $picture = '';
      }

  $data=array(
    'product_name'=>$this->input->post('product_name'),
    'produce_description'=>$this->input->post('produce_description'),
    'product_price'=>$this->input->post('product_price'),
    'picture'=>implode('|',$picture)
  );
  if ($id==0)
  {
    return $this->db->insert('products',$data);
  }
  else {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    return $this->db->update('products',$data);
  }
```

}
And this is my model function for getting data:

```
      public function get_product()
    {
   #code
   $query=$this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Any kind of help are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you mind sharing dashboard.php with specific line in it

Comment: explode('|',$p['picture']) will create an array and you are trying to print an array with echo ...

Comment: @Malik Mudassar the view i provided here is the dashboard.php

Comment: @MalikMudassar So what should i do, can you instruct me?

Comment: explode the names, keep them in an array and use the index you want when displaying products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this

```
<?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>
  <?php 
      // explode images into a variable/array
      $images=explode('|',$p['picture']);
   ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $p['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['produce_description']; ?></td>
      <!-- <td><?php echo $p['picture']; ?> </td> -->
      <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$images[0];?>" /> </td>
      <td>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/view/'.$p['id']); ?>">View</a> |
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/edit/'.$p['id']); ?>">Edit</a> |
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/delete/'.$p['id']); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

**Edit**

I will give you an example from a code in production at [this link](https://duperty.com/realestate/property/property_detail/20/4-CHEQUES2-bed-villastand-alone-unit-in-JVT-with-maidroom-and-huge-garden)

```
<div class="aa-properties-details-img" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
<?php
    $property[0]['images']=explode(',',$property[0]['img']);
    if(count($property[0]['images'])>0){
       for($i=0;$i<count($property[0]['images']);$i++)
       { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo  base_url().'img/'.$property[0]['images'][$i]?>" alt="img">
       <?php }
       }else{
       ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().'img/no-image.jpg'?>" alt="img">
       <?php
     }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: let me give it a shot.

Comment: yeah i did that and it worked. But i tried to upload multiple images to show them all. $images[0] is returning only one image man. how can i get all of them?

Comment: I have a show page which is linked from dashboard . In show page i want all the pictures of products to be displayed. So i did something like this: <?php foreach(explode('|',$show['picture']) as $pic) ?>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$pic['picture'];?>" />
  <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: on doing this it says unexpected foreach. How do i need to perform this action?

Comment: if you want to display all images, use some slider and loop through your images

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $p['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['produce_description']; ?></td>
      <td>
       <?php  $images=explode('|',$p['picture']); 
          foreach($images as $image) {
       ?>
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$image; ?>" width="50" height="50" />
      <?php } ?>
      </td>
      <td>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/view/'.$p['id']); ?>">View</a> |
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/edit/'.$p['id']); ?>">Edit</a> |
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('products/delete/'.$p['id']); ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: or if you want to make more columns you can use this code by Gaurav

Comment: but you have to restrict no. of images. how much you want show.

Comment: okay I get that. But I faced a problem. Suppose i need to delete any one of the image while I edit my post. Then how can i manage this imploded images names in database? Also the image is not deleted from the root folder /uploads/images/. When image or whole post is deleted the image should also be deleted right? How can that be done guys?

Comment: you have to re-submit all images name after deleting the image. In code you have take diff of both image array before delete and after delete. If diff come then you can delete that image from image folder. After that you save that image array by impoded.