# showing images from database stored using one to many relationship in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have uploaded multiple images for single product. The case here is I have products table and product_images table. These two tables are in relation. The product_id column of product_images table is made foreign key taking the product_id column of products table. Here is the detail code for it.[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221448/saving-multiple-images-for-one-product-using-one-to-many-in-codeigniter/43222068?noredirect=1#comment73517871_43222068)
now i have tried this way to access images. 
in my model, get function is :

```
    public function get_product()
    {
     #code
     $query=$this->db->get('products');
     return $query->result_array();
   }
```

and my view is:

```
    div class="container">
    <h2>Product Lists</h2>

   <table class="table table-striped, table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Product_Id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Product_Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Picture</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Options</strong></td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>

  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_name']; ?></td>
      <!-- <td><?php echo $p['picture']; ?> </td> -->
      <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$images[0];?>" />                      </td>
         <td>
         <a href="<?php echo site_url('#'); ?>">View</a>
      </td>
      </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

everything is working fine except it is not showing image. It is just showing crack thumbnails of image.

this is my storing function:

```
        public function set_product($id=0){
         $picture=array();
         $count=count($_FILES['picture']['name']);
        //Check whether user upload picture
       if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
         foreach($_FILES as $value){
         for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++){
           $_FILES['picture']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
           $_FILES['picture']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
           $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
           $_FILES['picture']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
           $_FILES['picture']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
           $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
           $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
           $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

           //Load upload library and initialize configuration
           $this->load->library('upload',$config);
           $this->upload->initialize($config);
           // print_r($value['name'][$s]);exit;
           if($this->upload->do_upload('picture')){
               $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
               $picture[] = $uploadData['file_name'];
           }
          }
       }
       }//end of first if
       $data=array('product_name'=>$this->input->post('product_name'));

       if ($id==0){
      $this->db->insert('products',$data);
      $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
      if(!empty($picture)){
        foreach($picture as $p_index=>$p_value) {
           $this->db->insert('images', array('product_id'=>$last_id,'images'=>$p_value));
         }
        }
      }
    else {
     $this->db->where('id',$id);
     $this->db->update('products',$data);
     if(!empty($picture)){
       foreach($picture as $p_index=>$p_value) {
          $this->db->update('images',             array('product_id'=>$last_id,'images'=>$p_value) ); // --> this one?
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve imploded images path in database to view in code igniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201645/how-to-retrieve-imploded-images-path-in-database-to-view-in-code-igniter)

Comment: @Gaurav Will that work? Thats not working

Comment: Why? and show me stored image path also what data are you storing in db for image.

Comment: @Gaurav I have uplaoded the upload function there you could see the image path . And image is stored for the product. One products can have many images. So i am using one to many relationship between the tables products and images as mentioned above.

Comment: now you have updated question.good.

Comment: you can join the table. after that in select statement use `GROUP_CONCAT` for image column.  `select products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) from products left join images on images.product_id=products.id`

Comment: @Gaurav I would be very grateful to you if you show it in code please. I have used relationship already should i need to write raw join query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
public function get_product()
{   
    $this->db->select("products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) as images", false);
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('images', 'images.product_id=products.id', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('products.id');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-striped, table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Product_Id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Product_Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Picture</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Options</strong></td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($products as $p): ?>

  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p['product_name']; ?></td>
      <?php $images = explode(",", $p['images']); ?>
      <td>
        <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/').$image; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
       </td>
       <td>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url('#'); ?>">View</a>
      </td>
      </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Array ( [product_id] => 8 [product_name] => gfdsdfgh [images] => 15400425_384280551914877_3607106669179553345_n.jpg,15400342_258695011214810_1240948716449811711_n.jpg ). This came when i did print_r($p). How can i access those images. When i did $p['images']. It didn't return anything.

Comment: `$images = explode(',' $p['images'])`

Comment: but how can I access the files in view page, where i need to get the tables attributes by its id, in this case product_id

Comment: You have to change in .htaccess file by adding upload folder. RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|themes) [NC]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139954/discussion-between-suz-aann-shrestha-and-gaurav).